# Jenkins: Send email to recipients of the triggered job

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have two Jenkins jobs. One trigger the other using "Parameterized Trigger Plugin".

In case of failure, the second build should send email using "Email-ext plugin".

The email should be send from the second job but to the recipients list of the first. I've tried using the parameters, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Email-Ext plugin has **Upstream Committers** option. Try updating.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your build steps, create a property file to send downstream and copy the file to the folder of the next job.  Use the [Inject environment variables plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) in the second job to import the file.

In Job 1's build steps you could do something like

```
echo Recipients_Notified=%BUILD_USER_EMAIL%, %Distribution_List% cc:%Dev-Group@email.com% > email.properties
echo Subject_Line=%APP% Pipeline>> email.properties
echo Line_1=information you want sent from first build to be in the communication>> email.properties
copy email.properties "..\%APP% Job Name\email.properties"
```

In Job 2 you can add to that file or overwrite it with a different message once the build is successful.  Importing the file a second time will overwrite the parameters imported the first time.